# Titanium UI Component size

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-alloy

Which unit (percentage or pixel or density pixel) need to be use while defining the user-interface component in Titanium?

I am facing problem when I am using view with in scroll view. Height and Top properties *(in %)* of view is not working properly.

Comment: Please post your code and specify what is the actual problem you are facing. Because we can use any unit that we want to create a UI, considering we understand the unit and its effect on device. if we talk about `%` then make sure the view's parent has a specific with height then only the percent would work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i can only recomend based on my own experience.
I use percent and dp, both are important to me.
Now, when you have to scroll something i use dp, specifying the layout: 'vertical' in the main view.
i think it depends on how you are building your UI.
Regards.

Comment: Agree... If you can provide an example of what you're trying to do, others may have some ideas...